# How to get media controls for Web Audio API on iOS and Android mobile lock screens?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web-audio-api, lockscreen

I'm developing a web app that plays many short samples via the Web Audio API. I'm trying to implement media controls on the mobile lock screens (both iOS and Android) using the Media Session API. Here's the code I'm using:

```
const initLockScreenCtrls = () => {
  if ('mediaSession' in navigator && !lockScreenControlsAreInit) {
    lockScreenControlsAreInit = true;

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function () {
      document.getElementById('playPause').click();
    });

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function () {
      document.getElementById('playPause').click();
    });
    console.log(navigator.mediaSession.playbackState); // yields "playing"
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', initLockScreenCtrls, {once: true});
```

This code sort of works on desktop (with an additional silent `<audio>` element hack, which I'd rather avoid), but doesn't help with the mobile lock screen controls issue.

How can I get lock screen media controls to work for the Web Audio API on mobile platforms?

Comment: FYI: I went through this article: https://web.dev/media-session/ and ran https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/audio.html on Chrome for Android on a Pixel3a Android 13 and able to see media controls on lock screen.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Any chance you could copy/paste your minimal example?  How was it different from mine? (As far as I can tell, I followed that guide too.)

Comment: Not an expert in javascript, but I noticed that you try to change state through the DOM rather than directly change the state as in the github example, https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/media-session/audio.js#L98 The example also uses async/await which I don't see in your code. Possibly related: https://w3c.github.io/mediasession/#dom-mediasession-playbackstate